# ggplot2 use toupper in aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to call `toupper` within my `aes` call in `ggplot2`. For example, using `PlantGrowth` I would like change variable `group` to all caps. I've been able to change the x labels to all caps, but then the x axis title takes on an odd title. I can manually drop the x axis title, but it seems like there is an easier way.

EDIT 1: I should have stated that I would rather not change the data in the dataframe, i.e., `d$group <- toupper(d$group)`. Instead I would like to change the labels within the `aes` statement, if possible.

```
library (ggplot2)
d <- PlantGrowth
p <- ggplot () + geom_bar (data=d, aes(toupper(x=group),y=weight),stat='identity')
p <- p + theme (axis.title.x=element_blank()) #workaround to drop x axis title
p
```

Thanks
-cherrytree

Comment: If you want to maintain the x axis title group, you can do `d$group <- toupper(d$group)` before you draw the figure.

Comment: you can overwrite any title including axis with `p + labs(x='Group')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `levels()`

```
library (ggplot2)
d <- PlantGrowth
levels(d$group) = toupper(levels(d$group))
ggplot() + geom_bar(data=d, aes(x=group,y=weight), stat='identity')
```

edit:
Does not change the data.frame version

```
library (ggplot2)
d <- PlantGrowth
ggplot() + geom_bar(data=d, aes(x=group,y=weight), stat='identity') + scale_x_discrete(label = toupper(levels(d$group)))
```

Comment: Technically you are using `levels<-`.

Comment: I would rather not change the data within the dataframe. I thought there would be a way to use `toupper` within the `aes`.

Comment: See edit for solution which does not change the data.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any other options, you can `library(tidyverse)` and `mutate` the `x=group` names using `toupper`. For example, `%>%  mutate(group= toupper(group)) %>%` before `ggplot()`.